# How to push branchs for different projects?

Tags: bazaar

I'm an Ubuntu translator and I like to translate `.po` files locally then push them to a branch.

If I'm working on more than one project and I need to push some changes to them after translation, will I need a separate branch for each project?

For example, I work on translation for `totem` and `nautilus`. Where should I push the changes to?

- a registered branch for each of them?
- a single branch?
- the project's branch itself?

Comment: I have edited your question a bit to make it a little more clear what you are asking. Please feel free to correct any changes I've made if any of them are incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean with a registered branch for each of them? In what way is that different from a single branch?

Comment: @jelmer : I meant what you replied for, that is, if I don't have write permissions to that project, I should create a new single branch(For each project I contribute to) and request for that to be merged into the project branch.
Cheers, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends a bit on whether your changes need to be reviewed first before they are merged, and what sort of access you have.

If you do not have write access to the project branch, or if your changes need review before they end up in the mainly you should create a new single branch and request for that to be merged into the project branch.